# Context menu item to lock/unlock files in Finder more quickly

Tags: macos, services, finder, automator

I can change the file locking ("read only") status in a file's context menu:

> [image]

There's no menu item for this.

How can I create a Finder (context) menu item to set, remove, or toggle this flag more quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new menu item that does that by creating a *Service* that receives *files and folders* as input in *any application* in Automator.

You have two implementation options. Choose one of the two Automator actions to build the Service workflow with:

- Run Shell Script
- Run AppleScript

The code below implements the *Toggle* command, as it's the most complex.

### Run Shell Script

This variant uses `stat` to read the flags set for the file. These are the same values as usually displayed by running `ls -lO`, but `stat` is a cleaner solution to read the values. The locked flag, or `uchg`, has the value `0x2`, so that's what we're checking for.

`chflags` is used to change the value, and `growlnotify`, optional part of [Growl](http://growl.info/), used to display success or error messages.

> [image]

Use the following bash script code snippet as part of the Run Shell Script action:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    let "$( stat -f "%f" "$f" ) & 0x2"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        chflags uchg "$f" || /usr/local/bin/growlnotify "Error" -m "Failed to lock $f!"
        /usr/local/bin/growlnotify "Locked File" -m "$f was locked!"
    else
        chflags nouchg "$f" || /usr/local/bin/growlnotify "Error" -m "Failed to unlock $f!"
        /usr/local/bin/growlnotify "Unlocked File" -m "$f was unlocked!"
    fi
done
```

Configure the action to receive input *as arguments*.

### Run AppleScript

Use the following AppleScript code snippet as part of the Run AppleScript action:

```
on run {input, parameters}
repeat with f in input
        try
            tell application "Finder" to set locked of f to (not locked of f)
        on error errmsg
            tell application "Finder" to display alert errmsg
        end try
    end repeat
end run
```

If the action fails, e.g. because permissions are missing, one dialog is displayed per file that failed to be changed.

> [image]